# 'Status Code : 405 Method Not Allowed' on loading comboStore

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to load a comboStore in my ExtJS combo.

```
this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
            autoLoad: true,
            url: 'NewJSON.json',
            storeId: 'projectDropDown',
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(
            {
                root: 'ROOT'
            }),
            idProperty: 'ProjectID',
            fields: [ 'ID', 'Text' ]
        });
```

I am getting Status Code : 405 Method Not Allowed'.

What could be the possible reason for this.

JSON

```
{
    "ROOT": {
        "Tag": [{
            "ID": 01,
            "TEXT": "B"
        },
        {
            "ID": 02,
            "TEXT": "A"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "url" and "reader" configs that you have placed in the store, are actually store [proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-proxy) configs.

```
this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'projectDropDown',
    fields: ['ProjectID', 'ProjectName'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'NewJSON.json',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'projects'
        })
    }
});
```

Also, the [idProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-idProperty) will not have any effect here, because it's an [Ext.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html) config. You should declare the model in a separate class, and then use it in your store.

Comment: Trying but not greeting much effect. I updated my question with a sample json data, Can you please give some light how I can bind my store with this json.

Comment: The JSON you've provided does not seem to be valid (you are missing a "]"). The reader's [rootProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html#cfg-rootProperty), judging by the JSON data, should be "ROOT.Tag". Take a look at this working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24om

Comment: That is fine. I correct the json. Here I am talking about `comboStore` not `GridStore`.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter. There are no separate stores for grids and combos. The same [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) class is used. Working combo fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24on

Comment: Ya, but unfortunately I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: j.on is not a function` error

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) that shows your issue? It's not very clear why it's not working.